# Class.forName(String) with dynamic string not working

Tags: java

This code:

```
private BasePlayer addPlayer(Player player) {
    BasePlayer currentPlayer;
    try{
      String playerClassName = this.getClass().getPackage().toString() + ".Player";
      Class cPlayer = Class.forName(playerClassName);
      Constructor constructor = cPlayer.getConstructor(new Class[]{ Player.class });
      currentPlayer = (BasePlayer) constructor.newInstance(new Object[]{player});
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
      log.info(e.toString());
      currentPlayer = new BasePlayer(player);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InstantiationException | NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException | InvocationTargetException e) {
      log.info(e.toString());
      return null;
    }
    log.info(player.getName() + " added to player list with UUID: " + player.getUniqueId().toString());
    playerMap.put(player.getUniqueId(), currentPlayer);
    return currentPlayer;
  }
```

throws the exception

> Java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: package com.warnea.codecraft.Player

however if I change

```
      String playerClassName = this.getClass().getPackage().toString() + ".Player";
      Class cPlayer = Class.forName(playerClassName);
```

to

```
      String playerClassName = "com.warnea.codecraft.Player";
      Class cPlayer = Class.forName(playerClassName);
```

it works fine.  Why do I need to seemingly hardcode the package name?

Comment: `package.toString()` prepends the name with `"package "`, which obviously will cause it to fail. Instead, use `this.getClass().getPackage().getName()`

Comment: The class is *not* 'package com.warnea.codecraft.Player'

Comment: @ernest_k, that worked. If you submit it as an answer, I'll accept it. Thank you.